# Turn literals into constants

Tags: vb.net

I am a new programmer learning Visual Basic.
Right now, I'm working on a project about a softball scoreboard. I have only ever used literals so I did not realize that my teacher wanted constants.

I am confused though because I am not really sure about the difference between the 2 or how I can turn my literals into constants.

I would really appreciate it if you could help. Thank you.

```
Public Class frmSoftballScoreboard
    'Declaring array
    Dim scores(7) As Double
    'declaring variables
    Dim runs As String
    Dim runningScore As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim out As Double

    'page load event
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lstScores.Items.Add("Runs Running Score")
    End Sub
    'Enter score button
    Private Sub btnScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnScore.Click

        If i < 7 Then
            'display inputbox to the user
            runs = InputBox("Enter score for " & (i + 1) & " innings", "Score")
            'if runs is entered
            If runs <> "" Then
                'parse the value of runs
                If (Double.TryParse(runs, out)) Then
                    'parse the runs and add it to the array scores()
                    scores(i) = Double.Parse(runs)
                    runningScore += scores(i)
                    'add the rainfall value to the listbox along with month name
                    lstScores.Items.Add(scores(i) & " :" & runningScore)
                    'increment the value of i
                    i = i + 1
                Else
                    'display error message
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter valid runs value")
                    lblTotal.Text = ""
                End If
            Else
                'if runs is empty then display error message
                MessageBox.Show("Enter runs for " & i & "innings")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Only sever innings are allowed")
        End If
        'calculate total runs And display on the lable
        lblTotal.Text = String.Format("final score is {0}", scores.Sum())
    End Sub
    'Clear Menu click
    Private Sub ClearToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuClear.Click
        lstScores.Items.Clear()
        lblTotal.Text = ""
        'reset i to 0
        i = 0
    End Sub
    'Exit Menu click
    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuExit.Click
        'close application
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `If i < 7` has an off-by-one bug.  Consider `If i < scores.Length` so you can store 8 values in the array.  And definitely consider List(Of Double) so these kind of artificial limitations don't exist.

Comment: Thank you, but what did you mean by List(Of Double)? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample how you can do it.

Old code with literal:

```
MessageBox.Show("All well done!")
```

Code with a constant instead:

```
Const SUCCESS_MESSAGE As String = "All well done!"

MessageBox.Show(SUCCESS_MESSAGE)
```

A sample with a placeholder in the constant:

```
Const REPLACE_MESSAGE_SAMPLE As String = "This is Number #!"

Dim i As Integer
i = 123

MessageBox.Show(REPLACE_MESSAGE_SAMPLE.Replace("#", i))
```

You could use any string you like instead of `#`. It's just a sample.

BTW: Your Code Looks like `VB.NET` and not `VBA`. I edited it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. That is really helpful. I just have 2 questions. Would I still be able to do the same thing with the message that has i in it> Also you modified my code so it is vba?

Comment: No, I didn't edit your code. I just changed the tag you used from `vba` to `vb.net`. Regarding your other question: I enhanced my answer above.

Comment: What about: `Const REPLACE_MESSAGE_SAMPLE As String = "This is Number {0}!`". And usage: `MsgBox(String.Format(REPLACE_MESSAGE_SAMPLE, i))`.

Comment: Absolutely right, I was in „VBA-mode“, where this can“t be done. ;-)

Comment: VBA-mode must be off! 

Answer (score 0):

You should use constants with placeholders:

```
Const WARNING_MESSAGE$ = "The player {0} must be ready at {1}"
MsgBox(String.Format(WARNING_MESSAGE, "John Davis", #12/11/2018#))
```